# How to exclude password field in the response in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express

Whenever a request is being made to the backend for getting a user, I'm getting this user back with the hashed password.

```js
        {
            "_id": "5e4e3e7eecd9a53c185117d4",
            "username": "rick",
            "email": "rick@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$/eD8g4jCw6Bx0.FNxFDADO5tc70AvUmK0H/7R/0JTyo2q9PcGAdOO",
            "createdAt": "2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

**User model**

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
    }]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

**listUser route**

```js
    listUsers: (req, res) => {
        User.find{}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error occurred" })
            } else if (!users) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "No users found" })
            } else if (users) {
                return res.status(200).json({ users: users })
            }
        })
    }
```

While I have declared the password field in the User schema, is there any way to get the response object back without the password field? I tried the option of `selected: false` on `password` field in User model, it worked but when I was unable to login in my app. There must be some other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could remove the field when making the query call  for example the below code finds a user based on id and removes the password field.User Being the User Schema,Hope this Helps

```
let user = await User.findById(id).select("-password");
```

Comment: How would you do it in the above route that I have written above, and other routes such as register, login, update,delete?

Comment: By The same rules changing User.find{} to User.find({}).select("-passsword") should work

Comment: you just need to attach .select("-fieldname") at the end of the query call , although i don't see the need to remove the password field from object if you are deleting a user or if you want to login a user because you would need to see the password matches the entered password before proceeding.

Comment: thanks. yes, we need password in register and login. also, why do we need password in deleting a user?

Comment: you don't need the password to delete a user,what i was saying is that there is no sense in removing the password field if you are about to delete the user object

Answer (score 8):

**Simple and preferrable way:**

You can change the default behaviour at the schema definition level using the select attribute of the field:

```
password: { type: String, select: false }
```

Then you can pull it in as needed in find and populate calls via field selection as '+password'. For example:

```
Users.findOne({_id: id}).select('+password').exec(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following operation finds documents in the `user` collection and return all field and exclude `password` field.

[here mongodb link for more info.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#explicitly-excluded-fields)

`let user = await User.find({},{password:0})`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { transform: function(doc, ret, options) { delete ret.password; return ret;} });
```

That gives you the possibility to exclude one field from the collection.

P.S.: The 3 parameters indicates the values of your schema. You can even put the parameter "Transform" while creating the Schema.